# Roblox Integer Value not changing

Tags: lua, roblox

I am creating a simple elevator using cframes.

I don't know if using remote events are appropriate for creating an elevator but these are the scripts:

```
--LocalScript located inside StarterPlayerScripts
local up = game.Workspace.Elevator.UpButton
local down = game.Workspace.Elevator.DownButton
local elevator = workspace.Elevator
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RemoteEvent1 = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvents.ElevatorUp
local RemoteEvent2 = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvents.ElevatorDown

while elevator.Area.Value == 2 and wait() do
    up.Icon.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
        RemoteEvent1:FireServer()
    end)
end

while elevator.Area.Value == 1 and wait() do
    down.Icon.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function()
        RemoteEvent2:FireServer()
    end)
end
```

```
--Script in ServerScriptService
local up = game.Workspace.Elevator.UpButton
local down = game.Workspace.Elevator.DownButton
local elevator = workspace.Elevator
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RemoteEvent1 = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvents.ElevatorUp
local RemoteEvent2 = ReplicatedStorage.RemoteEvents.ElevatorDown

local location1 = Vector3.new(126, 138, -6.5)
local location2 = Vector3.new(126, 22.5, -6.5)

RemoteEvent2.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    for i = 0,1,.00005 do
        wait()
        elevator:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(elevator.PrimaryPart.Position:Lerp(location2, i)))
    end
    elevator.Area.Value = 2
end)

RemoteEvent1.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    for i = 0,1,.00005 do
        wait()
        elevator:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(elevator.PrimaryPart.Position:Lerp(location1, i)))
    end
    elevator.Area.Value = 1
end)
```

The value of

```
game.Workspace.Elevator.Area.Value
```

isn't changing for some reason and I don't know why.

Comment: shouldn't `local elevator = workspace.Elevator` be `local elevator = game.workspace.Elevator`

Comment: @dt192, `workspace` is a global variable, just like `game`.